# how to delete contents of a file from main body of c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I wanted to know if I can delete the values (string or int) written in a file from main.
i.e. erase entire data in a text file and make it empty like before
If yes, how?

Comment: "make it plain like before" - what does this mean?

Comment: It means no contents in it as if the file were newly created

Answer (score 4):

Just overwrite it with a new, empty file:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream ofs("myfile.txt");
ofs.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ios_base::trunc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/ofstream/) openmode with ofstream:

> (truncate) Any current content is discarded, assuming a length of zero on opening.

Example,

```
std::ofstream ofile("filename.txt", ios_base::trunc);

//work with ofile

ofile.close();
```

Comment: +1. Indeed, you can erase a file *without* putting anything in `main`: `#include <fstream>` `std::ofstream f("name", std::ios::trunc);` `int main() {}`